# Python Subprocess.Popen and rdesktop

Tags: python, subprocess

I am building an app in python to connect to the various 127.0.0 addresses that are assigned to client systems, and use the correct credentials for that client. Issue I'm having is in this bit of code:

```
ip = get_int('Which IP? 127.0.0.')
fullip = '127.0.0.{}'.format(ip)
print ('Connecting to {} on IP {}'.format(curr_client.client,fullip))
command1 = ['echo', curr_client.passwd]
command2 = ['/usr/bin/rdesktop',
            '-g 1900x1000',
            '-a 16',
            '-u {}'.format(curr_client.user),
            '-p -',
            '-d {}'.format(curr_client.domain),
            '-r disk:luke=/home/luke/Work\ Stuff',
            '{}:9389'.format(fullip)]
print(' '.join(command1)+'\n'+' '.join(command2))
p1 = Popen(command1, stdout=PIPE)
Popen(command2,
        stdout=DEVNULL,
        stdin=p1.stdout,
        stderr=None,
        close_fds=True,
        shell=False)
```

p1 correctly echos the password, which I can see by shoving a print(p1.communicate()) in between the 2 commands.

If I take the output of `print(' '.join(command1)+'\n'+' '.join(command2))` and pipe the echo into the rdesktop call, it works correctly.

However, it fails to login when launched from inside this app. The actual command run (pulled from ps) looks like (user/domain redacted):
    `/usr/bin/rdesktop -g 1900x1000 -a 16 -u ****** -pXX -d ***** -r disk:luke=/home/luke/Work\ Stuff 127.0.0.13:9389`

Based on what I see on the login screen, its trying to use the XX as the password.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that popen was doing something odd with the spacing. I took out all the spaces between the option identifier and the option value, and its working perfectly now.

`command2 = ['/usr/bin/rdesktop',
                        '-g1900x1000',
                        '-a16',
                        '-u{}'.format(curr_client.user),
                        '-p-',
                        '-d{}'.format(curr_client.domain),
                        '-rdisk:shared=/home/luke/Work\ Stuff',
                        '{}:9389'.format(fullip)]`

Comment: POpen isn't being odd, the problem is that each list element is a single parameter. So, things like `'-g  1900x1000'` are passed in as a single parameter. The program's  command parser can handle them being 2 parameters `'-g', '1900x1000'` or one parameter without the spaces `'-g1900x1000'`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. I didn't come to understand that from reading the subprocess documentation. I had always thought of -g as the parameter and the 1900x1000 as the parameter value. I imagine understanding this better will aid me in the future.

Comment: I guess another way of saying it is that when using a shell, commands are broken into tokens based on things like whitepsace - these tokesn are passed to the underlying program as separate parameters. Popen, when using a list and without shell=True, doesn't do any tokenization so you have to have to separate the parameters yourself.